# Angular 6 NodeJS 8.4, I am using MEAN. I want to list the status of all id's stored in Mongodb to browser

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I stored the list of objects in MongoDB, I am able to list all of them in the browser and when I clicked the inventory button, it will use the routerlink to get the availability and list them. 
 Now I want to show the availability of all items while page loading.
I thought of using the foreach after received the data(array) from mongodb But I am not sure how to save the data before its going to next item in the loop.

```
My code for listing items stored in mongodb using express, mongoose- index.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AdUnit } from './AdUnit';
import { AdunitService } from '../../adunit.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  adunits: AdUnit[];

  constructor(private adunitservice: AdunitService) { }

  deleteAdUnit(id) {
    this.adunitservice.deleteAdUnit(id).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('Deleted');
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.adunitservice
      .getAdUnits()
      .subscribe((data: AdUnit[]) => {
      this.adunits = data;
    });
  }
}

HTML -index.component.html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
      <td>Ad Unit Name</td>
      <td>Ad Unit Price</td>
      <td colspan="2">Actions</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let adunit of adunits">
          <td>{{ adunit.unit_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ adunit.unit_price }}</td>
          <td><a [routerLink]="['/inventory', adunit._id]" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a></td>
          <td><button (click)="deleteAdUnit(adunit._id)"  class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The inventory details for each item available in /localhost:3000/:ID, and the output format will be {unit_name:"items", available_count:"00 - 99" }

Answer (score 0):

I used a for loop after getting the data from the DB, and created new array and copied the data from the data and response from "/localhost:3000/:ID". Then dispalyed the newly created array in the template URL